# HttpURLConnection sends + instead of space

Tags: java, http

I want to send http post request to some server and the parameters contain spaces as well as some special characters. the following is my code:

```
public static String HttpPost(String[] paramName, String[] paramVal)
{
    try{
    String parameters = null;
    if ((paramName != null ) && (paramVal != null))
    {
        parameters = paramName[0] +"="+ paramVal[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < paramName.length; i++) 
        {
            parameters+= "&";
            parameters += URLEncoder.encode(paramName[i], "US-ASCII") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(paramVal[i], "utf-8");
        }
    }
    //parameters = URLEncoder.encode(parameters, "utf-8");
    byte[] postData = parameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    int postDataLength = postData.length;
    FolderManager fm = new FolderManager();
    String urlStr = FolderManager.ApplicationUnderTestUrl();
    URL url = new URL( urlStr );
    HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
    conn.setDoOutput( true );
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
    conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );

    //con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); 
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=US-ASCII");
    conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=US-ASCII"); 
    conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "US-ASCII");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
    conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
    conn.setUseCaches( false );
    try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {

       wr.write( postData );
       //System.out.print(postData);
    }
    String line;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        return line;
    }

    reader.close(); 
    return line;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

The above code sends the special characters but it sends '+' symbol where ever there is a space in the params. How do I avoid this?

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do. Why do you think you need to avoid it? And please fix your title. It contradicts your question.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type on why the behaviour you are observing is correct

Comment: I am sending the names of some files and folders and some UI elements over to the server side and they have spaces in them. If '+'s are sent instead of spaces my server fails. So I need some way to avoid the replacement

Comment: You need to do a `URLDecode` on the server side. That should be converting '+' to spaces.

Comment: Or your server should be a servlet or JSP page or JSF bean, in which case it would all happen automatically.

Comment: My server is MAC (Cocoa) based so `URLDecode ` will not help.

Comment: Is there a way to send the parameters in the body of the request and not the url

Comment: @CodingIsComplex In a POST call, the parameters _must_ be in the body of the request instead of the URL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it to work. This is what helped:

```
if ((paramName != null ) && (paramVal != null))
    {
        parameters = paramName[0] +"="+ paramVal[0];
        URLEncoder.encode(parameters, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");
        for (int i = 1; i < paramName.length; i++) 
        {
            parameters+= "&";
            parameters += URLEncoder.encode(paramName[i], "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(paramVal[i], "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");
            //parameters += paramName[i] + "=" + paramVal[i];
        }
    }
```

Hope it can help you in some way too.

Comment: All you've accomplished here is a co-operating bug. The problem is at the other end. The request parameters aren't being decoded correctly. When they fix that, this will break.

Comment: There is no bug there, The decoder on server just decodes %20 to space in its parameters and not +. However the '+'s in the URL are decoded correctly.